# Call putty/plink to start a remote SSH linux script with user input

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, script, putty

Seemingly simple question, which yields slightly undesired results.

*Execute putty to start a script on a remote linux server which requires user input*

The remote script does a `read -p "Please enter name" NAME`
I can use `plink` to execute a script over SSH, the following attempts and problems are shown below :-
*Note the `-load ns` is to load a session that doesnt exist, ie ensure no defaults are used*

**1**) `plink.exe -load ns <ip_addr> -l <user> -pw <password> <script path/name>`
*Problem)* Doesn't allow/show user input, ie its non-interactive.

**2**) Add `-t` to allocate a pty :-
`plink.exe -t -load nc <ip_addr> -l <user> -pw <password> <script path/name>`
*Problem)* Ok, so now the user input can be seen, but I get Ctrl+H (^H) when backspace is pressed, *ok if the user doesnt make a mistake!*

**3**) Use putty instead with a saved session
`putty.exe -load "SavedSession"`
*Problem)* **(a)** Get a new window opened, not a biggy, but not as nice. **(b)** saved session cannot be easily [moved](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/putty-session.html). **(c)** Get password prompt, cannot provide password like with plink, *I know I know, use keys, but this is a closed, private network, and its easier not to bother with keys!*

So ideally, I would like the SSH to execute in-line, that is from within the batch file/command line shell I am in, not prompt for username/password, run the linux script and allow prompts and delete/backspace to work.

Many thanks for any ideas/solutions in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add -t to allocate a pty ... Ok, so now the user input can be seen, but I get Ctrl+H (^H) when backspace is pressed

Make your script run `[ -t 0 ] && stty erase ^H` and the Backspace key should be accepted.

An even better solution is to use a port of OpenSSH – for example, that from Cygwin or MinGW – it will give you full terminal emulation as PuTTY does, but keep it in the console window. (The *plink* tool is designed for raw 8-bit data transfers.)

**Edit:** A downside of Cygwin might be its lack of IPv6 support (if I remember correctly).

---

> Get password prompt, cannot provide password like with plink
>
> [...] but this is a closed, private network, and its easier not to bother with keys!

And yet you have a problem which setting up keys would solve :)

(I'll feel bad for saying this, but PuTTY also accepts `-pw`.)

Comment: Thanks, but I dont understand how to use the `[ -t 0 ] && stty erase ^H`, is that on the windows side? ie something like `plink.exe [ -t 0 ] && stty erase ^H -load nc <ip_addr> -l <user> -pw <password> <script path/name>` obviously doesnt work.

Comment: Yes I know, use keys! I could use `-pw` but not in conjunction with loading a Saved Session, of which is the only way to launch a script/command with Putty. ie either `putty.exe -load SessionName` (allows a script to be saved in the session settings, and ran) Or `putty.exe -t -load nc <ip_addr> -l <username> -pw <password>` just dumps you in a shell, I have to write this for dummies to use, so no typing in the shell!

Comment: re Comment#1, Ok, i was being stupid! Added it into the **Linux shell script** and it seems to work great! Will check back in a min when fully tested! Cheers!!!

Comment: And re OpenSSH via Cygwin or MinGW, would be nice, but this is a portable upgrade script, of which I can ship putty/plink binaries with the scripts, which tho not imposable with Cygwin (no idea about MinGW) is slightly harder to create portable versions of (or so I believe, anyway im going off-topic..)

Comment: @IanVaughan: Well, AFAIK, you only need to ship `ssh.exe`, `cygwin1.dll` (or the equivalent MinGW runtime DLLs) and maybe `libssl.dll`.